# PHP file - Populating a dynamic <select> tag with values from a database issues

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, forms, function

Okay my problem is i have a form which contains a select tag which needs to be dynamically populated from a Database, the values populated are determined by the postcode/zipcode a user enters **WITHOUT** submitting the form.

for example a postcode of 1234, the drop down list will contain values x1, x2, x3
but if a postcode of 4321, the drop down list will contain values y1, y2, y3

I have done some testing and my sql statement is perfectly fine, as i can populate the  tag on submitting the form, yet i dont know how to implement on how to do this without submitting the page.

I understand the difference between JS and PHP, but could a onblur() JS function be used to dynamically change the drop down device, with calling a PHP function or having embedded PHP code somehow inside...

im stumped on how to do this with just Javascript or PHP..(since it's an assignment) and yes i have looked on how to do this.

Comment: its better to use ajax for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need `onchange()` and an `ajax` method to re-load the select

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onchange

so once you select an option the select tree is re-loaded via ajax

Comment: ah yes, onchange i mean not onblur i will look at ajax now... Do you think its possible to use it without ajax?

Comment: @user2404755 without ajax you have to reload the enteire page for making select changes :) , ajax is the way to go in this case, trust me ;)

Comment: Okay, assignment is based on JS and PHP alone but I totally understand what you are talking about, i may need to take a different approach on how to implement this form. Thankyou!

Comment: since you got me in this problem, ill see if you can get me out.. you helped me heaps but now i realised that the devices cannot be submitted inside a form?

What would cause this?

Comment: @user2404755 please Define "devices"

Comment: input textboxs, drop down menus, etc

Comment: since, the populated drop down menu is being added from the ajax function, i have made that call a php file which then displays the drop down menu... it will not be picked up on submission or and JS

some sample code is in this question i posted..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706099/ajax-php-and-javascript-to-populate-a-form-input-device-issues

Comment: @user2404755 not quite clear , but do you know you can reload js as well as the php/html select via Ajax?

Comment: Don't ever link to w3schools!!